# React Router 4 with Mobx reinitializes component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mobx, mobx-react

I am using react router v4 with mobx, and I have run into a very annoyng bug.
This is my index.js

```
const history = createHashHistory();
render(
        <Provider history={history} {...stores}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Application />
            </Router>
        </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Inside Application I have a Menu component with navlinks and a Body, where I have a switch

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/somecomponent/' exact={true} component={SomeComponent} />
    { other routes>}
</Switch>
```

Both Application and Body are decorated with @withRouter, so routing works fine, but 
every time I navigate to '/somecomponent' a new instance of SomeComponent is created.
This is SomeComponent's constructor:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.store = new SomeComponentStore();
        console.log('reinitialising')
    }
```

And yep, console.log runs everytime I go to that route and a new store is created too (which is how I initially noticed the problem). All other component inside that Switch behave the same way.
Can anybody please explain to me what is causing the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React Router components do not render the individual routes when they are not active (i.e. the route does not match), this results in them getting unmounted and the instances destroyed. When they are active again they need to be reconstructed. If you view this component in React Devtools you will see that the components disappear completely.

This is expected behaviour and you should design your component hierarchy with this in mind. For example, if you want to maintain application state across route changes then move your state store above to a component whose instance is not managed by the router and pass it down as a prop.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I got really confused after googling my problem and finding several examples, where components didn't unmount and remount, but now I see that these were different cases - mostly there was just one component with different props for different routes. Now it all makes much more sense to me, thanks again!